# Whenever I run some kind of database operation (IE update_attributes, save etc.), timestamps are in UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

When I run:

```
psql great_dev -c 'show timezone'
```

The following is returned:

```
TimeZone  
------------
US/Eastern
(1 row)
```

I want the timezone  to be EST, so I think that is correct.  The problem is that whenever I run some kind of database operation (IE update_attributes, save etc.), the timestamps are in UTC like this:

```
SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "schedules" SET "accepted" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE 
 "schedules"."id" = 46  [["accepted", "only_freelancer"], 
 ["updated_at", Mon, 02 Dec 2013 16:51:07 UTC +00:00]]
```

I am starting to implement several background jobs and it is essential that I understand what timezone Postgres is in.

1. Is Postgres in EST or UST?
2. If it is in UST, how do I convert it to EST and is it dangerous to do so?
3. I am going to allow a user to enter in timestamps from a select menu - should the menu list UTC times or EST times?

Comment: Postgres is stores time in unix timestamp read here about conversion http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: I suppose you mean UTC where you wrote UST?

Comment: Rails prefers to have the database in UTC with all the time zone mangling in Rails-land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) type in Postgres is `timestamp without time zone`.
To deal with this, employ the data type **`timestamp with time zone`**.

Or run your database with the time zone set to UTC and use `timestamp [without time zone]`.
Be aware that the time zone setting of the session is relevant to what Postgres actually returns for your queries.

This related answer provides all the details you might need:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)